# Бэкап живой системы

Tags: резервное-копирование, ubuntu

На машине один раздел (ext4), куда установлено все. Периодически делается бэкап папки с данными

```
tar -cvjf папка.tar.bz2 папкаmv папка.tar.bz2 флэшка
```

Недавно система полетела. И пришлось переустанавливать и перенастраивать все, а не только данные. Каким образом лучше всего сохранить цельный образ живой системы, включая загрузочный сервер и тд. примерно, как в Windows делает Ghost?

Answer (score 1):

Для полной копии всего диска или нужных разделов подходит команда dd. Чтобы уменьшить конечный размер архива лучше забить пустое пространство нулями

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/root/zero bs=4M
```

а затем

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdXY bs=1M conv=noerror | gzip -c > /mnt/backup/root.dd.gz
```

Подробнее: [резервное копирование системы](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/backup).

Answer (score 0):

Порообуй это кокраз недавно снимал образы с серваков с raid контролерами http://www.clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 0):

rsync, tar Делать копию - делал, а вот восстанавливать из архива не приходилось, думаю, работать будет, но лучше уточнить.